# Finding the timestamps of processes implementing Lamport's clocks

Tags: computer-architecture, distributed-systems, computer-networks, process-scheduling, clocks

I have been asked this question, but don't know how to go about answering it.

Three process, which are implementing Lamport's clocks, are running and a lot of events are taking, place including some messages being sent between the processes. The arrows and circles represent in-processor events and messages being sent between process. Assume all clocks starts on 0 and the time goes from left to right. Provide the logical timestamps associated with each event.

[image]

To my understadning each circle will mean +1 increase in the proccess clock and the arrows means that it should add the time from where the process is from +1 to the process which receives the arrow. Is this a correct understanding of the task or am I missing something?